# Trying to append a Polymer element in another Polymer element

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

I have a **v-fire** Polymer :

```
<script>
    Polymer({
        is: 'v-fire',

        properties : {
            onFire: {
                type : String,
                reflectToAttribute: true
            }
        },

        firing: function () {
            this.fire('fire');
        }
    })
</script>
```

I want to be able to use it anywhere in my Polymer elements to make them trigger an internal function to make them perform a specific task like update, so they get all updated when the `v-fire` is calling `firing`.

For instance, I make a new object to test :

```
<script>
    Polymer({
        is: 'fire-tester',

        _updateContent: function () {
            alert('I get updated');
        }
    });
</script>
```

in **index.html**

```
…
<link rel="import" href="/components/fire-tester/fire-tester.html">
…
<body>
<fire-tester id="fire-tester"></fire-tester>
<script>
(function () {

    var ft = document.getElementById('fire-tester');

    // make a global v-fire Polymer
    var vfire = document.createElement('v-fire');
    // custom callback of the Polymer's that will include the v-fire
    vfire.onFire = '_updateContent';

    /**
     * And here, I try to insert the v-fire in the fire-tester Polymer
     */
    Polymer.dom(ft.root).insertBefore(
        vfire,
        Polymer.dom(ft.root).childNodes[0]
    );

    // the dom is pretty neat, fire-tester contains v-fire with the custom on-fire callback

    // then I try to fire the event
    vfire.firing(); // but nothing happen


});
</script>
```

It doesn't work because I believe the **v-fire** is not processed when inserted in **fire-tester**. Is there a way to tell Polymer to process the chunk of dom as if it was declared in the local DOM ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're approaching the events system incorrectly.  What you want is to run a method on `fire-tester` when it detects the `fire` event on the child `v-fire` element, correct?  This is how I would put that together:

**v-fire.html**

```
<script>
  Polymer({
    is: 'v-fire',

    firing: function() {
      this.fire('fire');
    }
  });
</script>
```

**fire-tester.html**

```
<script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'fire-tester',

      listeners: {
        'fire': '_updateContent'
      },

      _updateContent: function () {
        alert('I get updated');
      }
    });
</script>
```

**index.html**

```
<fire-tester id="fire-tester"></fire-tester>
<script>
  (function(){
    var ft = document.getElementById('fire-tester');

    var vfire = document.createElement('v-fire');

    Polymer.dom(ft.root).insertBefore(
        vfire,
        Polymer.dom(ft.root).childNodes[0]
    );

    vfire.firing();
  })();
</script>
```

Comment: nice! however, I realized I couldn't insert the `v-fire` in other Polymer elements rather than cloning it, which led me to loop on all the cloned `v-fire` as to fire a custom event throughout my app. I think there is another and a better approach of managing events in the application. I will gather the application's specific listeners in the root element and execute appropriate Polymer's functions as a response. thanks for your support anyways, it helped me to have a better view arrrr!

Comment: I really think it would be better to use behaviors instead if you would keep on reusing the same events on different elements.

Comment: Without seeing the whole project it's hard to tell, but it might also be more appropriate to include `v-fire` in the `fire-tester` template in the first place, or insert it as content.  Have a look at the `<content>` element and how it's used at https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/local-dom.html